# Postgresql Join on Select Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to do a join on a `Select` Statement in Postgresql, but I am having issues

```
SELECT 
    s.sessionid, sp.lang 
FROM 
    sessions s
INNER JOIN 
    pages sp 
ON 
    sp.sessionid =  s.sessionid 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        max(sessionid)
    FROM 
        sessions
    AS 
        maxSession
)
ON 
    maxSession = s.sessionid
WHERE 
    --Where condition
```

I get the following error:
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias

```
LINE 6: (
        ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

If I add the `FROM`

```
FROM
(
    SELECT max(sessionid)
    FROM sessions
)
AS maxSession
```

I get another error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 7:  FROM
```

Ideas?

Comment: remove the `ALIAS` on the subquery. it should be outside. `(
        SELECT max(sessionid) maxSession
        FROM  sessions
    ) AS   maxSession ON maxSession.maxSession = s.sessionid`

Comment: alias is manatadory

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are close.

```
  INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT 
    max(sessionid) as 'maxSession'
   FROM 
   sessions        
) maxSession
ON 
maxSession.maxSession = s.sessionid
```

Any time you refer to a query as a table, you need to give it an alias...alias goes right after the entire subquery, not in the subquery itself.

Comment: one more missing, you need to give an alias for `max(sessionid)`

Comment: ah yes, sloppy on my part.   fixxed...and just noticed you got to the error in a comment before my answer was posted.